# how to get and render selected values related data from array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have no expertise in javascript but I want to render this data which is showing in my `console.log` below

[image: array]

[image]

How can I make `forloop` or something like that to render this data in my html input?

`create.html`

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Expected Values</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{vital.expected_values}}" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{vital.price}}" readonly>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#id_vitals").change(function () {
            var vitals = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: $('#personForm').data('url'),
                data: { 'vital_id': vitals },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response[vitals['name']])
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it somehow like that:

```
// Your data
let dataArray = [{data: 1, otherData: 2, elseData: 3}]
// The element, where you want to show it
let targetElement = document.getElementById('your-targer-id');
// The container element for elements
let newContainer = document.createElement('ul');

// Pure JS loop, easy to understand what is happening
// But you can also do it with .map();
for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
  // Add every line
  newContainer.innerHTML+='<li>' + dataArray[i].data + '</li>'; 
  // Or other things, depending how you want to show the data
  newContainer.innerHTML+='<li> data value is: ' + dataArray[i].data + ' and otherData value is: ' + dataArray[i].otherData + '</li>'; //etc
}

// Append created list in target element
targetElement.appendChild(newContainer);
```

EDIT - now I see, that you want to display multiple values in text input, rather like so:

```
let dataArray = [...your-data-array]
let targetElement = document.getElementById('target-input');

for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.lenght; i++) {
  // loop throug elements and add it to value attribute of input, separated by coma.
  targetElement.value+=dataArray[i].expected_values + ', ';
}
```

Comment: please i don't know how to use this code in jquery would you like to explain it. how to use it?

Comment: please correct me i am doing something wrong data is not showing in input field i also update my question i have upload the image of my html code...